# Как в заголовочном файле увидеть класс, объявленный в другом заголовочном файле?

Tags: c++builder

Имеется класс в файле 1.h:

```
class TfrmMain : public TForm
{
    ...
}
```

а в файле 2.h попытка доступа к нему:

```
#include "1.h"
void initMainForm(TfrmMain* mainForm);
```

Но компилятор пишет, что:
**unknown type name 'TfrmMain'**

В чём ошибка?

Comment: Возможно, имеется циклическое включение заголовочных файлов, то есть заголовок 1,h в свою очередь содержит директиву #include "2.h" прямо или косвенно через включение других заголовков.

Answer (score 1):

Одной из причин может быть циклическое включение заголовочных файлов, то есть заголовок 1,h в свою очередь содержит директиву #include "2.h" прямо или косвенно через включение других заголовков.

Например,

**1.h**

```
#include "2.h"
class TfrmMain : public TForm
{
    ...
};
```

**2.h**

```
#include "1.h"
void initMainForm(TfrmMain* mainForm);
```

Comment: Ну да, есть циклическое включение. Первому файлу нужен доступ к функции из второго файла, а второму файлу нужен доступ к классу из первого. Что можно предпринять в такой ситуации?

Comment: @Александр Делайте предварительное объявление класса без его определения в заголовочном файле. В определениях другого класса используйте только объявления методов, которые ссылаются на первый класс.. А сами методы определяйте в cpp файлах вне классов.

Comment: Да вроде оно все так и есть:

http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-builder/thread2416991.html